# Excel VBA - compare date in cell to current week

Tags: excel, vba

please could someone help me. I have been trying and could not seems to resolve this.

I want to compare the date in Column J to the current week. My code also include finding the last row and automatically loop until the last row.

I currently trying with the following code but having issue with

```
Recievedate = Format(Cells(i, "J").Value, "ww-yyyy")
```

I have tried

```
Recievedate = Format(Range(i, "J").Value, "ww-yyyy")
```

which was found in another post but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me what have I done wrong please? Please ignore the code after MsgBox "OK" as I am trying to build this step by step. Thank you.

```
        Sub macro1()
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select ' Find last row in column A and remember the active cell
       
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Recievedate As Date
    
    For i = 2 To ActiveCell.Row 'start from row 2 and automatically +1 until it reach the active cell
    Recievedate = Format(Cells(i, "J").Value, "ww-yyyy")
    
        If Recievedate = Format(Date, "ww-yyyy") Then
        MsgBox "OK"
        
        End If 

Next i

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub macro1()
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select ' Find last row in column A and remember the active cell
       
    Dim i As Integer
    ' Dim Recievedate As Date
    Dim Recievedate As string
    
    For i = 2 To ActiveCell.Row 'start from row 2 and automatically +1 until it reach the active cell
    Recievedate = Format(Cells(i, "J").Value, "ww-yyyy")
    
        If Recievedate = Format(Date, "ww-yyyy") Then
        MsgBox "OK"
        
        End If 

    Next i
```

With this statement `Recievedate = Format(Cells(i, "J").Value, "ww-yyyy")` you assign a string to `Recievedate` which cannot work in case `Recievedate` is declared as `date`.

Another approach could be to use `WorksheetFunction.WeekNum` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected as you suggest and it works.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution - note, no `Selecting` required.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ReceivedDate As Date
    
    For i = 2 To lRow
        ReceivedDate = Cells(i, "J")
        If Format(ReceivedDate, "ww-yyyy") = Format(Date, "ww-yyyy") Then
            MsgBox "Row " & i & " is ok.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is interesting. Could you share what is the benefits of not using selecting please?

Comment: If the user selects a different cell while your code is running, if the cell that is being selected is locked so the code can't select it... basically giving the user a chance to muck up your hard thought over code.  There's an (almost) obligatory [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) that deals with avoiding select.

Comment: Thank you. I will improve my code with this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look for a date that is between the start and end dates of the current week.

For example (assuming your week starts on Sunday and ends on the subsequent Saturday)

```
Sub CurrentWeek()
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim dtBOW As Date, dtEOW As Date
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    
dtBOW = Date - Weekday(Date - 1) 'Beginning of week
dtEOW = Date + 7 - Weekday(Date) 'End of week

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(10) 'Column J, fully qualified

For Each c In r.Cells
    If c >= dtBOW And c <= dtEOW Then
        MsgBox "found it at " & c.Address
        c.Select 'Selected only so as to highlight it on the worksheet
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next c

MsgBox "no luck"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a benefit using this method over the 'ww-yyyy'?

Comment: @Crabscoot You avoid the overhead of converting all of your existing dates to strings before doing the comparison.

Comment: ah ha.. thanks, didnt think it that way. Will try to adapt and improve.